# Short key to stop VLC player

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, vlc-media-player

I have training curse video that runs on vlc player on second monitor. I do sample exercise in Visual Studio on main monitor while watching video. Sometimes I need to stop video in fast way and for this reason I don't want use mouse. I need to stop video with help of short key combination. How to achieve that?

UPD:
I have installed AutoHotKey, but keys are working only when vlc window is active

Comment: Have you got multimedia keys on your keyboard? if yes, the pause button should do

Comment: I have som e keys for internet exploring, but no multimedia. Can I somehow redefine them?

Comment: *"I have installed AutoHotKey, but keys are working only when VLC window is active."*  Unfortunately, you will find that is typically the way that it will work.  For better or worse, the fastest way to pause that video is probably going to involve utilizing the mouse.

Comment: Try the following. This may also work with non-media keys. Note that you must utilize the "Global" setting and will need to restart VLC for the changes to take effect: https://superuser.com/a/750103/122089

Answer (score 0):

global shortcut keys work as Beems pointed out, but I needed to do it from AHK because I needed to do other commands too
this ahk script works for me (win+numpad 5 to toggle playback)

#Numpad5::

ControlSend,, {Space}, ahk_class QWidget

Answer (score 0):

```
^Space::
WinGetTitle, title, A  ; Get Active Window Title
WinGetClass, class, A  ; Get Active Window Class
WinGet, process, ProcessName, A  ; Get Active Window Process
WinActivate, VLC media player ahk_class Qt5QWindowIcon ahk_exe vlc.exe  ; Send Space To VLC
Send, {Space}  ; Send Space To VLC
WinActivate, %title% ahk_class %class% ahk_exe %process%  ; Activate Previously Active Window
Return
```

Answer (score -1):

“Space bar” to pause playback “s” to stop 
Go to tools, preferences, hotkeys to change if required

Comment: This shortcut will only work when vlc is the active window

Comment: Option tab will cycle through open applications (alt tab for pc) this is how I use it and it works fine as long as you have only gone into one application so it’s not several tabs away then can perform action of option tab, space fairly quickly.

Comment: We always appreciate contributions from our new community members, but I think that you might be missing the point that @DaveM is trying to make.  The OP specifically said that *"I have installed AutoHotKey, but keys are working only when vlc window is active."*  In other words, they already found a solution that will work if you toggle over to VLC as the active window.  They are asking for one that will work when VLC **isn't** already the active window.